# CMS development

Tags: content-management-system

I'm new to this CMS techmology.My company is telling me to develop a CMS for multiple companies with the company info to be stored in the database.The second thing is this that they haven't given me the design of the CMS as well as the Main Website.The website look should be generic that suits any generic static website.I'm not able to find any good looking template for this.I've searched a lot but not able to find a good one.And what kind of database design that i should use.If any one could also provide me what features should a CMS that our company is looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Your first port of call shoudl be http://www.opensourcecms.com/ - check out as many open source and commercial CMS offerings to see if any would suit your needs. If nothing else, it might help refine your requirements by understanding what you *don't* need.